# Print composer: Frozen layers disappeared after server migration

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.10

I am currently working on a project file with around 30 print composers using different layers. Some of the layers come from a PostGIS database connection, others were imported through the Add Layer menu. Some layers have styles applied from locally saved .qml files, other styles were set manually. Every print composer has at least one map window and every single one of those map windows has its layers frozen (so I can modify the styles and the layer order for one of the composers without affecting the 30 other composers).

Now, I work in an office setting and the project, as well as some layers and all of the .qml files, are saved on a network mapped drive. The address of the mapped drive was recently changed due to a migration on a newer server. The first time I opened one of the print composers after the server migration, I noticed that while all the layers did appear in the project itself, none of them would show up in the print composer as they should, considering that were frozen in a map window. I assume that the Freeze Layers function depends on an absolute path to the layers or something.

This is a major inconvenience as it means that I will have to manually re-arrange the layer order, styles and labeling for 30+ print composers. Does anyone have an explanation as to why this happened? Is there a way to fix it, like by fiddling with the .qgs file?

Comment: Open the project file and check the paths on the layers for start.

Comment: Also freezing the map in the composer doesn't freeze the style, only visible layers.

Comment: I've checked the paths and they seem to be OK. I don't get any error message when I open my project file and all the layers are there, they've disappeared in the print composers only.

Comment: As for the style, I have checked both boxes in every print composer: Freeze layer and Freeze styles.